# C++ Multimap No Matching Member Function Insert

Tags: c++, data-structures, associative-array, multimap

```
#include <map>
.
.
.
multimap<double, pair<int,int>> weightList;

for(int row = 0; row < matrixSize; row++ ){
    for(int column = 0; column < matrixSize; column++){
        double weight = matrix[row][column];

        weightList.insert(weight,make_pair(row, column));
    }
}
```

So I'm getting an error that says "no matching member function to call insert". I don't know how else to insert into a multimap. If you have any idea how else I could insert into the multi map I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried std::make_pair? Also multimap.insert requires a pair type, so you would do something like insert(std::pair<double, pair<int,int> >)

Comment: Shouldn't it look rather like: `weightList.insert(make_pair(weight,make_pair(row, column)));`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments try with

```cpp
 insert(std::make_pair(weight, std::make_pair(a,b)));
```